# How to add atribute to Xml?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I have a request that as an atribute called operation="V" (fwxtrasptos001 operacion="V"). This is the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<envelope>
    <version>v1.001</version>
    <tipo_codificacion>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</tipo_codificacion>
    <fwxtrasptos001 operacion="V">
        <origen_peticion></origen_peticion>
        <clientNumber></clientNumber>
        <cardNumber></cardNumber>
        <points></points>
    </fwxtrasptos001>
</envelope>
```

This is my request class

```
@Xml(name = "fwxtrasptos001")
data class TransferPointsValidationRequest (

        @PropertyElement(name = "origen_peticion")
        val petition:String,
        @PropertyElement(name = "clientNumber")
        val userNumber:Long,
        @PropertyElement(name = "cardNumber") 
        val cardNumber:Long,
        @PropertyElement(name = "points")
        val pointsToTransfer:Long  
)
```

This is my request envelope:

```
@Xml(name = "envelope")
class EnvelopeTransferPointsValidation (

        @Element(
                typesByElement = [
                    ElementNameMatcher(type = TransferPointsValidationRequest::class, name = "fwxtrasptos001")
                ]
        )
        val body: SoapRequestBody,

        @PropertyElement(name = "version")
        val version: String = "v1.002",

        @PropertyElement(name = "tipo_codificacion")
        val codificationType: String = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

)
```

With the code I have how can I add the atribute fwxtrasptos001 operacion="V" to the begin xml tag

Answer (score 0):

A start tag consists of an element name plus zero or more attributes (keyword/value pairs). The corresponding end tag must contain the (same) element name; it cannot contain attributes. So the name in the end tag must match the name in the start tag; the attributes are not part of the name.

I'm not familiar with the technology you are using, but I suspect that your code `name = "fwxtrasptos001 operacion='V'` reflects this misunderstanding: you should only include the name here, not the attributes.

**NOTE**

The question has been heavily edited since this answer was written, so the answer may now appear to have little relevance to the question.

Comment: Can you show an example with my code please? When I close the tag with the begining tag the API gives me an error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sufficiently familiar with the APIs you are using. All I can see is that you are confused about the XML concepts and terminology, so I've tried to put you right on that.

Comment: Yes I was confusing terms. It is called an atribute that belongs to xml. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help :)